# how to tell if a site is made with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

can you tell if a site is made with cakephp, how,

how to check it - to check any folders, initial pages , to see some specific queries ?

Comment: What do you think about asking the author? :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this CMS detector](http://guess.scritch.org/) can help you. HTTP headers in many cases reveal a lot about technology used to power a site.

Answer (score 2):

1) find a form on it, if it has values in the format data[Something][whatever] chances are its cake

2) url format is normally /something/anotherthing/id and a lot of times there will be some urls like /pages/something, also wont often find extentions in the url

3) check the name of the main css file, some people wont change it, cake.default.css iirc

4) try going to a random url and see what the error looks like, default cake will be something like "Error: The requested address '/sdfsdfsfsd' was not found on this server."

5) if the url is site.com/something/etc and you can go to site.com/index.php?url=/something/etc

obviously these can all be done on any system, but its a pretty good giveaway if the all/mostly work

Comment: Apart from the cake.css all these 'signs' can be relevant for Symfony / ZF as well.

Comment: thanks, i already pointed that out. and you can call a file cake.whatever in anything too.

Comment: With CakePHP 3, This is not true. form inputs have now a clean name without array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WhatWeb](http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/whatweb) which is created for this purpose and has a plugin for cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool I made called PageXray, it can detect CakePHP apps.

http://pagexray.com

It uses some quick Curl techniques to check if files exists, if some css or images are in webroot and also checks the page's header for some CakePHP signatures.

Then for a list of sites that was made with cakephp, check this out.
http://pagexray.com/technologies/php_cakephp.htm